# OAuth2 and jwts am I using it securely?

Tags: authentication, security, oauth-2.0, jwt, google-oauth

I was build a CRUD web application React and Spring Boot.
Needed authentication and as such authentication. Instead of me storing users credentials and sensitive data I thought I would use google for this.

Correct me if any of reasoning here is wrong, first time using Oauth.

I use OAuth2.0 to get user credentials from google, which ome in the form of a jwt, containing: email, username, normal jwt fields and an id (used by google).

So now I have information for frontend page renders. But what now?
When I try to Create (for example) a Budget (has a field identifying the creator) on the server what do I send?

- The Budget.creator filled with "user@gmail.com"? Then anyone can just say they are the user@gmail.com and the server will just have to believe them.
- The JWT? But what if an attacker just goes ahead and creates a jwt with "user@gmail.com" and sends it? Server can't validate that google sent this jwt

So here I guess is where a token would come in, right? When user first logs in to google I would get a token (with expirationDate) and be able to use this to get the credentials of said user. With this token I can now send it to the backend (maybe in http header Authorization) and through an API call google to fetch user credentials.

Is my thinking correct? Because I have looked at some code examples online and I did not find anyone (or at least the majority) using these tokens...

**Side-note:** not sure on how I can generate this token with google in react (but generally in any language), also what server endpoint to call to verify token.

Know this was an heavy question/topic, thank you for answering in advance!

Edit: What I have done is from Frontend (React) get and access_token from google, which I can use to fetch credentials, and I pass it to backend so it can also fetch these credentials. This seems secure, what are your opinions, is this done correctly?